# How can I cross validate the uniqueness of two columns, username and email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user model with a username and email. Currently, the email is used to log in, however I want users to be able to log in with their username as well. In order to do this, I have to ensure that one users username is not the same as another's email, and vice versa.

My uniqueness validations for each individual field work fine, but I can't get validation across the columns to work.

My validations are as follows:

```
validates(:username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false })
validates(:username, uniqueness: {scope: :email, case_sensitive: false});
```

And

```
validates(:email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
        format: {with: VALIDATE_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false })
validates(:email, uniqueness: {scope: :username, case_sensitive: false})
```

How can I validate the uniqueness of these two columns?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I validate the uniqueness of these two columns?

You could write a custom validation method:

```
validate :uniq_username_and_email

private

def uniq_username_and_email
  self.errors.add(:username, 'already taken') if User.exists?(email: username)
  self.errors.add(:email, 'already taken') if User.exists?(username: email)
end
```

Assuming that your model is named `User`

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Do you know why my original validations didn't work?